# admin-post.php not calling custom handler hook

Tags: php, wordpress

I've got a basic email form that I want to use a custom handler on. I tried following this tutorial https://blog.osmosys.asia/2016/05/07/handling-form-submissions-in-wordpress/ but it seems that my custom hook is not being called.

```
<form class="" action="<?php echo admin_url('admin-post.php') ?>" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="bb_submit_email">
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" value="example@email.com" required>
        <?php wp_nonce_field('submit-email', '_mynonce'); ?>
        <input type="submit" class="float-right btn btn-primary form-button" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php
add_action('admin_post_bb_submit_email', 'bb_handle_email_submit');
add_action('admin_post_nopriv_bb_submit_email', 'bb_handle_email_submit');

function bb_handle_email_submit() {

$logger = wc_get_logger();
$logger->add('submit-email-debug', 'triggered!'); 

    

if ( !isset($_POST['_mynonce']) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['_mynonce'], 'register-user')) {
    return;
}

wp_remote_post('example.com', $_POST );
}
```

I tried using `wp_ajax` instead but that didn't work either. Anyone see something I'm missing here?

Update: I don't know if this helps but I checked the POST Request data and it has the following:

```
action: bb_submit_email
email: example@email.com
_mynonce: a2c0e80de7
_wp_http_referer: /
```

That all looks right to me?

Answer (score 0):

I moved this

```
<?php
add_action('admin_post_bb_submit_email', 'bb_handle_email_submit');
add_action('admin_post_nopriv_bb_submit_email', 'bb_handle_email_submit');

function bb_handle_email_submit() {

$logger = wc_get_logger();
$logger->add('submit-email-debug', 'triggered!'); 

    

if ( !isset($_POST['_mynonce']) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['_mynonce'], 'register-user')) {
    return;
}

wp_remote_post('example.com', $_POST );
}
```

to `functions.php` and it started working. Honestly  not sure why?